# Indexing with range names while using SpreadSheetGear's Advanced Cells API

Tags: excel, spreadsheetgear

I'm dealing with Excel file containing many sheets and even more formulas. I can reference all the 15K+ input cells with their range names, which is much nicer and readable than just using column-row indexes, like `"AE2318"`.

Since the file is huge, I want to use `SpreadsheetGear.Advanced.Cells` interface to take advantage of any speedup possible. I noticed however that `IValues` interface can be indexed with 0-based row and column indexes.

How could I still use range names to refer to cells?

One thing I thought is to construct a dictionary, where I would store which ranges (cell with a given range name) resides on which sheet and which row/column. In Excel on the `Formulas` ribbon there's the `Name Manager`, which contains all this information, but how can I access that with `SpreadSheetGear`? The information is available from VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Named Ranges via:

1. IWorkbook.[Names](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook~Names.html)[...], which will include all Named Ranges for the entire workbook.
2. IWorksheet.[Names](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Names.html)[...], which will include "worksheet-scoped" Named Ranges for a given worksheet.

These collections can be iterated over via a `foreach` loop which would return an [IName](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IName_members.html) object for each Named Range.  You can also index into these collections via the Named Range's (string) name, or index within the collection.  Once you have an [IName](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IName_members.html) object that represents a given Named Range, and assuming it actually refers to an underlying IRange (consider that Named Ranges could also refer to static values such as `="Hello World!"`), you can use IName.[RefersToRange](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IName~RefersToRange.html) to get that IRange object and any zero-based row/column indexes and row/column counts (IRange.[Row](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Row.html)/[Column](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Column.html) and [RowCount](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~RowCount.html)/[ColumnCount](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~ColumnCount.html)) for use in the "high performance" [IValues](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Advanced.Cells.IValues.html) interface.

Comment: That sounds like what I need! I'll try it

Comment: Works well. However I'll get more ranges in that big registry than I expect, but I can sort them out.